# Terminology for using "the" instead of plural

Tags: terminology

I'm wondering about the following construction:

> The dog is a noble animal.

This seems to have the same meaning as:

> Dogs are noble animals.

I'm wondering if this sort of construction, referring to "the X" instead of X in the plural has a particular name.

Comment: @KannE, that exactly answered my question, thanks.